# focus variant and @apply directive do not work on nextJS

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

I have a new nextjs project set up along with tailwind.
I have a component with the folling class:

```
<a
className="inline-block px-5 py-3 rounded-lg transform transition bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 hover:-translate-y-0.5 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-offset-2 active:bg-blue-700 uppercase tracking-wider font-semibold text-sm text-white shadow-lg sm:text-base"
href="#"
>
  Instalar
</a>
```

and since I'm using it multiple times, I'm trying to create a class for it, and use it.
So I defined a custom class on my globals.css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-rgb:  255, 255, 255;
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: rgb(var(--background-rgb));
}

.btn {
    @apply mt-6 shadow bg-blue hover:bg-lightBlue-500 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded
}
```

But if I use it, then I got the following error:

```
./app/globals.css:16:5
Syntax error: /xxxxxxxxx/globals.css The `focus:shadow-outline` class does not exist. If `focus:shadow-outline` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
```

since the classes applied directly on the component do work, I don't understand the whys of this misbehavior.

here is my tailwind.config.ts:

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    backgroundColor: theme => ({
      ...theme.colors,
      'blue': '#4994EC'}),
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

Answer (score 1):

### I think this solves your issue -

**app.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 0 0 0;
    --background-rgb: 255 255 255;
  }

  html,
  body {
    @apply text-myForeground bg-myBackground;
  }
}

@layer components {
  .btn {
    @apply mt-6 shadow bg-myBlue hover:bg-lightBlue-500 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
  }
}
```

Just move it into layers. It is better practice to have the colors done this way -

**tailwind.config.js**

```
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        myBlue: "#4994EC",
        myForeground: "rgb(var(--foreground-rgb) / <alpha-value>)",
        myBackground: "rgb(var(--background-rgb) / <alpha-value>)",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Don't override existing colors just add a prefix/suffix to your colors.